# Searching for product codes, but the code contains letters

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm using this to find products by id.

```
function BuscarCodigo(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        const codigo = document.getElementById("buscar_codigo").value;
        const url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        const urls = url + "Compras/buscar";
        $.ajax({
            url: urls,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                codigo
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != 0) {
                    $("#error").addClass('d-none');
                    var info = JSON.parse(response);
                    document.getElementById("id").value = info.id;
                    document.getElementById("nombre").value = info.nombre;
                } else {
                    $("#error").removeClass('d-none');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my html:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="buscar_codigo">Cógigo producto</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                        <input id="buscar_codigo" onkeyup="BuscarCodigo(event);" class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Código producto">
                        <span class="text-danger d-none" id="error">El producto no existe.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Producto</label>
                        <input id="nombre" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="nombre">
                        <br />
                        <strong id="nombreP"></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but it only find something if it's a numeric id like "202324", the problem begins when the product code is like "FADA111", what can I use to find codes that doesn't contains only numeric characters?

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. It is hard to see what the issue is.

Comment: `document.getElementById("id").value` works with strings and not just numbers. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I just edited the question, thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
I followed the error from the errors that the console was throwing, the problem was in my Model.

This was my model

```
public function buscarProducto(int $codigo)
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = '{$this->codigo}' AND estado = 1";
        $res = $this->select($sql);
        if (empty($res)) {
            $res = 0;
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

I changed to this:

```
public function buscarProducto(string $codigo)
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = '{$this->codigo}' AND estado = 1";
        $res = $this->select($sql);
        if (empty($res)) {
            $res = 0;
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

The value I was getting was (int $codigo), just edited to (string $codigo), working now.